# Java primitive type object deserialisation auto-casting problems

Tags: java, oop, serialization, syntax, deserialization

I have this class:

```
public class AttrRepository {

    private HashMap<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    @Override 
    public HashMap<String, Object> save() {
        return attributes;
    }

        @Override 
        public void load(HashMap<String, Object> serializable) {
            this.attributes = serializable;
        }

    }
```

the load and save use java's ObjectOutput and ObjectInput streams.

When saving HashMap with this then loading it again, for some reason, everything at the value side of the table turns into a string.

**For example:**

```
  attributes.put("strength", 100.0); //set strength to 100.0 as a DOUBLE
  attributes.put("age", 0); //set age to 0 as an integer
```

but after saving it and loading it...

```
Double strength = (Double) attributes.get("strength");
```

throws a casting error... Cannot cast String as Double.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Java primitive types aren't `Object`(s). When you use `100.0` as an `Object` it's autoboxed to `Double` (the wrapper type). You should be getting a compiler error, saying `Object` is not assignable to `Double` without a cast. **Please** post a MCVE.

Comment: It looks like above code is working fine.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I edited the question to add a (Double) cast before the getter, which I forgot to do

Comment: @BhavikAmbani It should, I don't see anything wrong with it but for some reason I get casting problems and everything is a string now

Comment: I believe I have provided enough information. When setting a map value, saving it, then loading it- the type is modified without warrant

Comment: ```System.out.println(attributes)``` before serializing and after deserializing.

Comment: That is what you claim, but it doesn't make sense. Maps don't change member types. Serialization doesn't do that either. Conclusion: you must have some bug in one of these parts! Therefore: you should step back and create that minimal but complete example that allows us to repro your issue. Otherwise your question should be put on hold for "not reproducible". You see, you claiming that your code is all fine, but at the same time, the code is supposedly leading to these problems, that doesn't go together.

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that some part of *your* code is modifying the contents of your map at some point. Maybe a an attempt to trace values, that does put(key, value.toString()) or something like that.

Comment: I can,t see any DB table definition so my guess is that col2 is VARChAR and on persist the .toString method of object is callde. Then there will be no bug thus all you need to do is Double.parse Double, Integer.parseInteger, etc..